# Change iframe values in textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

My code:

```
<p>
<label for="color">Choose a color</label>
<input type="color" name="color" id="color">
</p>

<p>
<label for="width">Change width</label>
<input type="text" name="width" id="width">
</p>

<textarea id="iframe_url" name="iframe_url" rows="3">
<iframe id="widget" src="http://domain.tld?e=1&color=#f5f5f5" width="650" height="600">
</textarea>
```

I use jQuery to access textarea value.

```
<script>
var iframe = $("iframe_url").val();
</script>
```

I need to change color hex in iframe src url

I need to change iframe width / height from input

Comment: You can alter the "src" attribute using the jQuery's `.attr()` method.

Comment: If you're setting those attributes in the HTML string from the inputs, why do you have the string editable in a textarea? It would make more sense to build the string after the inputs are filled out and then just display it as a string in another (uneditable) element.

Comment: @laylarenee How can i do that ?

var iframe = $('#iframe_url').val();
iframe.attr('width', '700');
or
iframe.width('700');

But its not good :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan True !

Comment: You are trying to use jquery methods on a string (textarea value). You would need to first convert that string to an element (jQuery object) ...manipulate the element, then return it as html string back to textarea. But if whole purpose of textarea is only for this iframe html I agree that there are better ways to do this

Comment: To alter the "src" attribute, you could: `$("#widget").attr("src", "https://www.youtube.com/");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `replace` with `regexp` to update the string from the textarea.

```js
$('#color').on('change', function() {
  var updatedContent = $('#iframe_url').val().replace(/color=\#{1}\d*\w*/, `color=${$(this).val()}`);

  $('#iframe_url').val(updatedContent);
});

$('#width').on('change', function() {
  var updatedContent = $('#iframe_url').val().replace(/width="\d+"/, `width="${$(this).val()}"`);

  $('#iframe_url').val(updatedContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>
  <label for="color">Choose a color</label>
  <input type="color" name="color" id="color">
</p>

<p>
  <label for="width">Change width</label>
  <input type="number" type="number" min="0" step="1" name="width" id="width">
</p>

<textarea id="iframe_url" name="iframe_url" rows="3" readonly>
<iframe id="widget" src="http://domain.tld?e=1&color=#f5f5f5" width="650" height="600">
</textarea>
```